# Mongoose one has many relations between Schemas

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I know that this question has been raised many times before and that Mongo doesn't have that exact "has many" connection, but I failed to make connections between two schemas so far. Here is what I have:

User model (user.js)

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    posts: {
        _id : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },
        title : {type: String, ref: 'Post'}
    },

    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    }
});
```

And posts schema (post.js)

```
var meetingsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    _owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    ownerName: { type: String, ref: 'User' },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

I use schema population and it works perfect with post: each one of them has owner. However, it doesn't work that well with users. I want to be able to retrieve list of users showing posts that belong to them. In routes.js I defined an api call to database

```
app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    User.find(function(err, users) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(users); 
    }).populate('posts._id', 'posts.title');
});
```

But, both in shell and (not surprisingly) on clientside user.posts returns empty array. How can I bind these two models correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess.

1. You `User.find` all the users.
2. Then you return them all.
3. Then you populate post ID and title, which is already **too late** because you sent the users already.

See the population examples [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Additionally, I expect the `.posts` property to be an array, not just plane object. See `comments` property [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your link to "posts" on user is not an array? So only linking one post?